# shared memory vs texture memory in opencl

Tags: image-processing, opencl

I am writing deinterlacing code in Opencl. I am reading the pixels using read_imageui() API in the local memory.

Just like the code at:
https://opencl-book-samples.googlecode.com/svn-history/r29/trunk/src/Chapter_19/oclFlow/lkflow.cl

As per my understanding when we read pixels using this API we are reading from the Texture memory. I am doubtful that using the pixels first in shared memory will help me gaining any speed as Texture memory already acts as cache and provides fast access to data.

Can anyone clarify my doubt ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If you can fit all your data in private memory after reading it with read_imageui, you should definitely do that. Keep in mind that you only have 256 bytes of private memory per work item if your kernel compiles SIMD16 and 512 bytes if it compiles SIMD8.
2. Whether you should use local memory or not really depends on the access pattern. Indeed, Samplers have their own L1 and L2 caches, so if your data accesses always hit the caches, you should be fine. Remember, that local memory is banked, so you have 16 banks from which you can fetch 4 bytes at a time, which means that you get full bandwidth if you hit all 16 banks from all work items in one hardware thread (typically 16 or 8 of them). So, you might have a situation where you are better off reading image data into local memory first and then accessing local memory in an orderly fashion. Good example of this are algorithms like SIFT or SURF, where you access image in such a way that sampler cache really does not help much (you still get sampler interpolation benefits), but then you place all that data in local memory and access it repeatedly in a fairly regular pattern.

Answer (score 1):

In general, that's true. However, even a cached read from a texture *might* be slower than a read from shared local memory, so for an algorithm that makes many overlapped reads from adjacent locations could still benefit somewhat from using shared local memory. However, it will make the kernel more complicated, so for many cases (and certainly during algorithm development) just rely on the cached texture reads.